# C# .net and ASP -- Need to know how to call the url string from C# code and place it in asp code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is what I have but it's not working.

So instead of having Web Site I would like it to show the actual address coming from the database that's stored in lblWebSite.NavigateUrl

I tried changing it to lblWebSite.Text but that showed the web address, but did not act as a link. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

ASP CODE:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lblWebSite" runat="server" Target="_blank">Web Site</asp:HyperLink></span>
```

C# CODE:

```
this.lblWebSite.NavigateUrl = dvInfo.Table.Rows[0]["Uri"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set both the `Text` and `NavigateUrl` of the `Hyperlink` control to be the web address:

```
string url = dvInfo.Table.Rows[0]["Uri"].ToString();
this.lblWebSite.NavigateUrl = url;
this.lblWebSite.Text = url;
```